# VS2017 C++ project resource usage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, resources

I am using VS2017 and purely C++ projects.

I have a bitmap entry in "the.rc" file and a ID in "the.h" file similar to below:

the.rc

IDB_BITMAP7 BITMAP DISCARDABLE "something.bmp"

the.h

#define IDB_BITMAP7 7004

In the code I am developing I need the string "something.bmp", but only have the resource ID.  How can i convert IDB_BITMAP7 to "something.bmp"?

CString file_name = ???(IDB_BITMAP7);

Thank you for the help.  I am new to using resources in VS.

Comment: Why do you need the file name?
Once the bitmap is compiled into the executable, from the POV of the running program the bitmap file is not a thing. This is like asking how to recover the filename of a "main.cpp" etc. from the running program.

Comment: Good question :)  I am new to MFC, so please be patient.  I am using IPicture::Render to show the oic on a MFC form.  Right now I load the picture then render it.  Now sure how to just use the resource ID.

Comment: am using CreateFile(TCHAR, . . .) but tried to use CreateFile(MAKEINTERSOURCE(ID),. . .) but compiles and crashes

Comment: What are you trying to do? if what you want is to display the bitmap you dont need to call CreateFile or load the bitmap from a file.

Comment: This is 20 year old code and I have just taken it over.  I do not want to rewrite it just make it so I do not have to install the pic files with the installer.

Comment: The resource ID is used to uniquely identify the resource, just use the resource ID directly. It looks like you want to load a bitmap, then use `LoadBitmap(ID)`.

Comment: Again, it would be easier to provide an answer if you would tell us what it is you are trying to do. You do not need to install image files if you have compiled the images into the executable as resources and you want to display them in your application.